# How do you combine multiple document queries in spring-data-mongo-reactive?

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm very novice to reactive streams and have some doubts.
Let's say I have a service where I want to return a report about a person, the returned object have the following structure:

```
data class Report(
    val person: Person,
    val addresses: List<Address>,
    val jobs: List<Job>,
    val credits: List<Credit>
)
```

Each field in report will be filled for a different collection, how is this done in the reactive way? In the traditional blocking way, I would write something like:

```
fun getReport(personId: String): Report {
    val person = personRepository.findById(personId)
    val addresses = adressRepository.findByPersonId(personId)
    val credits = creditRepository.findByPersonId(personId)
    val jobs = jobRepository.findByPersonId(personId)
    return Report(
        person = person,
        addresses = addresses,
        credits = credits,
        jobs = jobs
    )
}
```

But I'm unsure what it's the way this should be done with reactive programming. I don't know if `concat` in combination with `collectMap` can be used here and will appreciate some light in this topic.